# Почему не работает start /b + exit /b?

Tags: bat

Я работаю на Windows 10 Home. Архитектура ARM 64-битная. У меня есть два батника:

a.bat:
`@echo n>n.txt`

b.bat:

```
start /b a.bat
exit /b
```

Почему когда я запускаю b.bat, a.bat не работает ( не создаётся файл n.txt с содержимым n)? И, если нет, есть ли альтернатива этим двум строкам?

Программа b.bat должна вызывать a.bat, а вторая работать в тихом режиме. Также команды b.bat складываются в одну, чегоя НЕ хочу.

Comment: Странно, у меня всё работает. Только потом по exit не выходит из командной строки. Вы как батник запускаете? Из того каталога, где он находится?

Comment: Да, с рабочего стола.

Answer (score 0):

Вызвать bat-файл из bat-файла можно через CALL:

**b.bat**:

```
call a.bat
exit /b
```

Comment: К сожалению, не работает.

Comment: и какую ошибку пишет?

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл ответ. Суть моей программы заключалась в скрытом запуске программы, чего я достиг, добавив в начале кода строку

```
@echo off>nul
```

Вместо обычного @echo off

Comment: и каким образом эта строка влияет на вызов вложенного бат-файла?